# Passing array from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

I am trying to pass an array from parent to child but I get the value `undefined` when I view it in child. I have tried the solutions here to resolve it.

`DvnlandingComponent.ts` (parent)

```
       import { HttpService } from '../services/http.service';

   export class DvnlandingComponent implements OnInit {
   count: number = 0;
   constructor(private http: Http,
   private service: HttpService)
   ngOnInit() {
        this.printConfigNames();
    }

            printConfigNames() {
        this.service.getAllconfigNames();
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
<results-component *ngIf="activeTab === 'Results'" [cfn]="configNames"></results-component>
```

`ResultsComponent.ts` (Child)

```
import { DvnlandingComponent } from './../dvn-landing.component';
     export class ResultsComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() cfn: any[] = [];
          ngOnit() {
        console.log(this.cfn);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
          if (typeof changes['cfn'] !== 'undefined') {
            console.log(this.cfn);
    }
    }

            printConfigNames() {
        console.log(this.cfn);
    }
```

HTML

```
        <select>
                <option selected>Select Config Name</option>
            <option *ngFor="let n of cfn" value="n" (click)="printConfigNames()">{{n}}</option>
        </select>
```

My service

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  getdata: any;
  count: number = 0;
  public configNames = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

      getAllconfigNames() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.set('JsonStub-User-Key', '157abb1d-fc96-4e00-83c7-9f286f6ef518');
        headers.set('JsonStub-Project-Key', '720d2af8-f159-41b4-9746-0476793869b4');

        let getUrl = 'http://jsonstub.com/getAllSchedulerConfigs';
        return this.http.get(getUrl, {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.getdata  = res.json();
            while (this.count < this.getdata.length) {
            this.configNames.push(this.getdata[this.count]['configName']);
            this.count++;
        }
        });
      }
      getData() {
        return this.configNames;
      }

    }
```

Comment: where is `configNames` defined??

Comment: `configNames` isn't defined in your `DvnlandingComponent`. Try adding `configNames = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with you code.

(i) There is no **`configNames`**  in your parent component. Make sure you have defined it.

```
configNames: any[];

printConfigNames() {
    this.service.getAllconfigNames().subscribe(res => this.configNames = res);
}
```

(ii) You are initializing to empty array on child component, which will clear the elements in it

```
 @Input() cfn: any[] = [];
```

change it as

```
 @Input() cfn: any[] ;
```

(iii) Your child Component should implement **`OnInit`**

export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log(this.cfn);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the service, but assuming you are using observables, in the parent:

```
configNames: any[];

printConfigNames() {
    this.service.getAllconfigNames().subscribe(res => this.configNames = res);
}
```

Should hopefully help.